# How to modify the paths of js from twentytwelve theme?

Tags: javascript

`<?php wp_head(); ?>` from my default wp theme generates

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js?ver=3.5.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
```

The question is... What is generating those two lines and how can i edit that code?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to edit that code?  These scripts are core scripts, enqueued by WordPress itself.

Comment: Hi @EAMann! I simply want to change the filepath; removing `wp-includes` , `?ver=3.5.1` / `?ver=1.8.3` and add google's hosted jquery with local fallback. The problem is that i didn't found anything that make reference to that piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable `comment-reply` go to `Discussion Settings` and disable `Threaded (nested) comments`.

Google-hosted jQuery:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'jquery', // name
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js', // google hosted, protocol-independent
        array(), // dependencies (empty)
        NULL, // removes version
        true // load in footer, 'false' for header
    );

}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1):

Those lines are inserted by functions hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` as in [this example from the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Examples):

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('scriptaculous');            
}    
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

The scripts themselves were registered and/or enqueued with [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) or [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

You can deregister or dequeue script with [`wp_deregister_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) or [`wp_dequeueu_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script)

In your case:

```
wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
wp-dequeue_script('comment-reply');
```

**But this is a good way to break things.** I would not deregister or dequeue core scripts unless I were personally managing a site and would continue to do so for the foreseeable future.

[Use Google Libraries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/) should load scripts form Google's servers in little bit safer way that just loading your own local copies.

Comment: I added that code to functions.php but it doesn't work.